# Getting error trying to deploy rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep getting

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

when I try to deploy my Rails application.

I already have a `package.json` file in my root directory.

I already have a `Gemfile` in my root directory.

I already set my buildpack to `heroku/ruby`.

This is a picture of the full error on the Heroku dashboard:

[image]

Here's the repo if that helps: https://github.com/TrentCodes/AboutMeWebsite.git

Comment: There should be a lot more information preceding "app not compatible". Please [edit] your question and include the full set of errors. Also, is your file called `gemfile` or `Gemfile`? Those are different things.

Comment: It is "Gemfile" with a capital G. The website runs perfectly on my local machine but when i try to deploy it with Heroku it fails to deploy because the app in not compatible with the Ruby buildpack. That is the only error I receive.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have a `package.json` file in my root directory.
>
> I already have a `Gemfile` in my root directory.

No you don't: they're in [a folder called `aboutmewebsite/`](https://github.com/TrentCodes/AboutMeWebsite/tree/master/aboutmewebsite).

You need to move everything that's in that directory up to the root directory (the folder that currently contains `README.md` and `aboutmewebsite/`).

> I already set my buildpack to `heroku/ruby`.

You'll [also need](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) the Node.js buildpack if you intend to have dependencies from your `package.json` installed. Something like

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

should do it. Run `heroku buildpacks` afterwards to make sure that the Node.js buildpack is first and the Ruby buildpack is second.

Comment: Thanks @Chris this worked and the app deployed to heroku. Only problem now is when I open the app on heroku I get an application error. Terminal also shows: Process exited with status 127
2019-09-08T18:57:44.747012+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory

Comment: @TrentCodes, that's a separate issue. If you need to ask about it you should do it in another question. However, [a quick search for `bin/rails`](https://github.com/TrentCodes/AboutMeWebsite/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bin%2Frails&type=) shows that [that is hard-coded in a file called `bin/setup`](https://github.com/TrentCodes/AboutMeWebsite/blob/88f23d337a007f6a011cca3836d1e214b8b8b758/aboutmewebsite/bin/setup#L29). It probably shouldn't be. Just use `rails`, which the buildpack should have made available automatically.

Comment: I'm not a Rails person, but that whole `bin/` directory looks suspicious to me. You shouldn't be shipping libraries or third-party executables in your repository. Use a `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` and a `package.json` / `package-lock.json` to define your dependencies, and nothing else.